# Vue in Laravel project doesn't appear

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm starting to work with laravel and I try to use Vue. So on my `resources/assets/js/app.js` I have

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app'
});
```

So my Example.vue is basicly what it's given with laravel. And in my welcome.blad I have

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <example>
    </example>
@endsection
<script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

in my package.json I have :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3"
}
```

But Nothing appear in my welcome page. I ran npm install npm run dev And change several things in my script, don't remember all but tried a lot of things and can't make it work

Comment: Check the console for errors. Is there a `<div>` with an id of `app` in your layout?

Comment: @ceejayoz there is, I'm not sure if example must be inside or outside de div but I tried both. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'csrfToken' of undefined`

Comment: I'd fix that bit first, then see if more errors. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf for details on the CSRF token.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ok I managed to fix that and that worked, thought it was two completly different things so thank you !

Comment: Many JS errors will interrupt execution of the remaining JS. Console should always be first stop. Glad I could help!

Comment: @ceejayoz Could you make a proper answer so I can validate it and close the topic ? If you want I can do it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel includes in the stock templates some default handling for [CSRF tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'csrfToken' of undefined
```

means you've taken this out or broken it in some way, preventing the rest of the JS from running.